# Two divs side by side inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple html code.

```css
.body-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.left-menu {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}

.right-container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle-view {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.right-view {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
  <div class="body-content">
  <div class="left-menu">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="middle-view">
      def
    </div>
    <div class="right-view">
      ghi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the following result:
[image]

But I would like to 'def' and 'ghi' side by side.

I don't have much experience using HTML and CSS but I thought middle-view and right-view together will fill right-container (70% + 30%). But as I see the width given to left-menu (50px) has impact on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution..

```css
.body-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  float:left;
}

.left-menu {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}

.right-container {
    background-color: blue;
    width:calc(100% - 50px);
  float:left;
}

.middle-view {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.right-view {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-content">
  <div class="left-menu">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="middle-view">
      def
    </div>
    <div class="right-view">
      ghi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @gabe3886 This works because .right-container is floated left. Problem is that, if you want to float it, you have to specify width in order for it to be full-width.

Comment: @Armin whilst I know why it works, just giving the code doesn't help people learn from the answer easily.  I'd suggest your information forms part of the answer to supplement the code.

Comment: @gabe3886 I agree that answers should contain more information and additional explanations. But I usually prefer to comment, instead of down-voting, even though latter seems to be more efficient :)

Comment: Thanks to Michael_B but as a person who has very little experience with .css and .html this answer seems more clear ;)

Comment: No problem @AshotKhachatryan. Just keep in mind that floats for layout are the past. CSS3 Flexbox and Grids are the future, and flexbox is already widely supported.

Comment: @Michael_B I will keep that in mind too :) Thanks for the nice answer to this question..

Answer (score 3):

```css
.body-content {
  display: flex;              /* forces children to same row */
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.left-menu {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.right-container {
  display: flex;              /* forces children to same row */
  flex: 1;                    /* consume remaining space on the row */
  background-color: blue;
}
.middle-view {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.right-view {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-content">
  <div class="left-menu">abc</div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="middle-view">def</div>
    <div class="right-view">ghi</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better answer imho.